# How can I theme the Views Exposed Filter Results page?

Tags: views, theming

I'm trying to theme this page

```
http://208.87.22.137:50000/admin/rooms/bookings/list/kiosk/3?name=rest
```

which is the result of an exposed views filter. I have themed the node the views block is on but I'm not sure how to theme this page since it's not using node/NID.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the devils module to get theme help. Also there is the `<?php print $classes; ?>` function that i have for instance on my div  with the class container div. And there I see for example the class page-searchresults. Giving away that I can use page--searchresults.tpl.php as a template file for theming that page.